# css table misaligning the second column when placing the scroll bar

Tags: html, css

This only happens when I put the scroll bar in the body of the table.
my code:

```
.fixroll-thead, .fixarrolagem-tbody { 
  display: block;  
}
.fixroll-tbody {
    height: 28rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width:100%;
    float: left;        
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTgPm.png)

Comment: I didn't understand what is the misalignment that you are trying to fix. Can you clarify or post a picture with what are you expecting to do?

Comment: the second column of the table is not at the end of the right side, the header goes to the end of the table, but the second column should also be until the end, there is an image in the link "example"